# Translation Golf: "Car Talk" Excerpt for some fun

Tags: traducción, translation-golf, inglés

Basic Idea:  Translate the following text faithfully, using as few letters as possible.  Anyone can play.  Pick a style, say what it is, and be consistent.  If your text is accepted as a valid translation, and is **more concise** than anyone else's, then you'll be declared the winner, and you'll get to propose the text for the next round.  Post your character count in bold.  On your mark, get set, go!  You have one week before the gong sounds.

> #### Unencumbered by the Thought Process
>
> **by Tom and Ray Magliozzi**
>
> Tom: Back around 1973 we opened a place called “Hackers Haven,” where
> people could rent our tools and fix their own cars.
>
> Ray: We figured it was a “can’t miss” idea.  We saw ourselves standing
> around in white lab coats and collecting the money while people lay
> under their cars and banged their own heads on transmission housings.
>
> Tom: But, alas, it didn’t work out that way.  You see, most people
> needed help.  Before we knew it, we were helping them fix their cars.
> And they were standing around in white lab coats and we were banging
> our heads on their transmissions.
>
> <sub>*(496 characters.)*</sub>

*slightly edited excerpt from their book,* Ask Click and Clack: Answers from Car Talk

Basic translation (684 characters) provided for reference (hover over the yellow if you want to see it):

> Sin responsabilidad por el proceso de pensamiento 
>  
>  por Tom y Ray Magliozzi
>
>
>  Tom: Alrededor de 1973 abrimos un taller llamado "Hackers Haven" (Albergue de los Reparadores Amateur de Autos), donde la gente podía alquilar nuestras herramientas y componer sus propios autos.
>
>
>  Ray: Pensamos que era una idea que no podía fallar.  Nos imaginamos sin gran cosa que hacer, vestidos de bata blanca de laboratorio, recibiendo el dinero mientras la gente trabajaba debajo de sus coches, dándose golpes en la cabeza contra sus transmisiones.
>
>
>  Tom: Pero, lástima, no salió así.  Lo que pasó fue que la gente necesitaba ayuda.  Pronto nos encontrábamos ayudándoles a componer sus coches.  Y ellos eran los que no tenían gran cosa que hacer, vestidos de bata blanca de laboratorio, y nosotros éramos los que nos dábamos golpes en la cabeza contra sus transmisiones.

The [fine print rules](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2592/12637)

Have fun!

*And the winner is... Diego at 344 characters.*

Comment: ¿Es que nadie va a participar esta vez? ¿Vamos a tener que dar por clausurada la temporada de _translation-golf_?

Comment: ¿Qué quiere decir _Unencumbered by the Thought Process_? ¿Es posible traducirlo como "pensar sin responsabilidad" o es más bien "no es necesario pensar"?

Comment: @fedorqui - Es una frase muy chistosa, por lo menos para mí.  Hmm.  ¿Cómo explicar?  Voy a hacer un intento, no será nada conciso: *Ofrezco mis ideas con pura inspiración de fantasía, sin obstáculos presentados por esfuerzos de pensamiento, por pensamiento sistemático o racional. Si en algo atino a ofrecer alguna idea productiva, alguna aportación positiva, será por pura chiripada.*

Comment: ¡Ya veo! Lo que coloquialmente llamaríamos _paja mental_ :D Por cierto, qué curioso que digas _chiripada_. En España usamos _chiripa_.

Comment: Quizás fue un error incluir "Unencumbered by the Thought Process."  @fedorqui se acerca más pero de veras es una frase difícil. // No he evaluado lo demás todavía, pero si me dan un poco más tiempo, lo haré.

Comment: ¿Se podrá usar *bricolaje* en el contexto de la reparación de autos?  ¿O es mejor "hazlo tú  mismo" para "DIY"?

Comment: @Diego - You could ask everyone to use the spoiler code to post!  I don't think there should be an advantage to posting first.  And having won once, I think it's fun to participate but winning is a big responsibility.

Comment: I actually believe it is a disadvantage. If you come late you get "ideas" from others. Although there is no easy workaround I don't think it is a real problem. People are just having fun here and there is nothing to win but the next round. I just wanted to give players some heads up.

Comment: @Diego - Okay, but I'm going to continue to make my first draft blind.  I think it's more fun that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## 344 characters

> **Claridad Mental**
>
> por Tom y Ray Magliozzi
>
> Tom: En 1973 abrimos "Hackers Haven", permitiendo alquilar herramientas para reparar autos.
>
> Ray: Una idea infalible. Nos veíamos cobrando en bata de laboratorio con la gente bajo su coche dándose con la caja de cambios
>
> T: Falló porque se necesita ayuda. Sin darnos cuenta pasamos a ayudarles, con ellos parados en bata blanca mientras nosotros nos golpeábamos con la caja de cambios.

---

Hice mi traducción antes de mirar las otras (para no tener una ventaja injusta sobre las otras aportaciones).

- He traducido muy libremente el título
- La segunda vez que se referencia a Tom uso solo la inicial, como se suele hacer en las transcripciones de entrevistas
- Uso un `se` impersonal para "most people needed help"

Creo que conservaba casi todo el significado del original, pero ya decidirán el OP y el resto de jugadores.

Comment: Tienes toda la razón en que en las entrevistas se suelen abreviar los nombres una vez introducidos, pero tengo mis dudas de si poner "T" por "Tom" incumple la regla de no usar abreviaturas. La duda viene de que estamos acortando un nombre propio (y no un sustantivo cualquiera) y que como dices es una práctica común.

Comment: Creo que deberíais decidir el resto de participantes, en especial @aparente001 porque es el "propietario" de esta partida sobre si vale poner la "T" o tiene que ir todo el nombre. Aparte aparente001 debería pronunciarse sobre si mi traducción del título (y las de los demás) es válida o no. El arbirto tiene que decidir si se mantiene el sentido o si solo le estamos dando "hachazos" al texto original para hacerlo más corto.

Answer (score 1):

### <strike>368</strike> 347 characters

> **Pensamientos al azar**
>
> por Tom y Ray Magliozzi
>
> Tom: Allá por 1973 abrimos el "Hackers Haven", donde alquilábamos herramientas para reparar coches.
>
> Ray: Una idea infalible. Nos veíamos en bata blanca cobrando y viendo a la gente bajo sus coches, partiéndose las astas con la transmisión.
>
> Tom: Pero qué va. Muchos querían ayuda y, al poco, se la dimos. Ellos acabaron en bata blanca viendo cómo nos partíamos las astas con la transmisión.

---

Notes:

- There's no need to translate the name of the store.
- As in English, the verb *alquilar* means both "to obtain the possession and use of a place or article in exchange for rent" and "to allow the possession and use of property in exchange for rent".
- *[Partirse/Romperse los cuernos](http://dle.rae.es/?id=BakkB8M)* = *Esforzarse, trabajar mucho.* The expression "to bang one's head on/against something" figuratively means to struggle very hard on some endeavour; hence the Spanish expression "partirse los cuernos", which I think is the closest match in our language.
- When you say *bata blanca* it is implied that it is a lab coat.

---

Updates:

- Changed the title after the OP's explanation.
- Changed *los cuernos* to *las [astas](http://dle.rae.es/?id=44bSLKZ)*, meaning the same thing.
- Changed *no fue así* to *[qué va](http://dle.rae.es/?id=M5ucdgy#BGv7dG3)*, used to denote incredulity or negation.
- Changed *Mas ¡ay!* to *Pero* to avoid archaic expressions.
- Simplified the sentence about starting helping others to fix their cars.

Answer (score 1):

#### 426 caracteres

> **Pensando sin cargas**
>
> por Tom y Ray Magliozzi
>
> Tom: Hacia 1973 abrimos el "Hackers Haven", donde alquilábamos útiles para arreglarse el coche.
>
> Ray: Nos pareció una idea genial. Nos veíamos con batas blancas recogiendo dinero mientras la gente yacía bajo su coche golpeándose la cabeza contra cajas de trasmisión.
>
> Tom: Pero, ay, no funcionó así. Muchos necesitaban ayuda. Al poco, estábamos ayudándoles a arreglar el coche. Y ellos se posaban con batas blancas y nosotros nos golpeábamos la cabeza contra sus cajas de trasmisión.

No acabo de entender bien *Unencumbered by the Thought Process* y de momento lo traduzco como *Pensando sin cargas*. Indicadme si no es correcto.

Answer (score 1):

An amalgam of various entries, with a few additional ideas, but not intended as a competing entry.  I'm posting this because there were some parts of the original where I felt the charm and gentle humor needed to come out more.  Also I used some tricks to get a bit more succinctness (see notes below).

### 341

> **Sin atascarse con exigencias racionales**
>
> por Tom y Ray Magliozzi
>
> **Tom**    Por 1973 abrimos un taller mecánico *hazlo tú mismo* con alquile de útiles, el *Hackers Haven*.
>
> **Ray** Idea genial: descansar en bata blanca mientras nos pagan por darse un coco con la caja de cambios.
>
> **Tom** Pero ¡ay! La mayoría necesitaba una mano.  Al poco pasamos a prestar ayuda, dándonos el coscorrón mientras el cliente descansaba en bata blanca.

Notes: I'm not sure if "darse un coco" and "coscorrón" work in this context; I'm not sure about "atascarse" -- this is my first time using this word in this way.

Tricks: using the present tense ("nos pagan") to describe the basic idea; using the singular ("el cliente descansaba") to convey the plural in an established context.

In the last line I reversed the order of what the client and the owners did, to make it flow better and to save some characters.