# Translation-golf VI: Sandkings by George R. R. Martin

Tags: traducción, translation-golf, inglés

[George R. R. Martin](http://www.georgerrmartin.com/) es el conocido autor de la saga "[Canción de Hielo y Fuego](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canci%C3%B3n_de_hielo_y_fuego)", llevada a la pequeña pantalla como "[Juego de Tronos](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Juego_de_tronos_(serie_de_televisi%C3%B3n))", título de la primera novela de la saga. Antes de alcanzar el increíble éxito de crítica y público por esta saga, Martin ya había recibido varios premios *Hugo* y *Nébula* por sus obras cortas de ficción en los años setenta.

El transaltion-golf de esta semana es un fragmento de *Sandkings*. El protagonista, Simon Kress, conoce estas *formas de vida* de la mano de Jala Wo.

> **Sandkings**
>
> “Note the colors, if you will,” Wo told him. She pointed to the creatures that swarmed over the nearest castle. One was scrabbling at
> the tank wall. Kress studied it. It still looked like an insect to his eyes. Barely as long as his fingernail, six-limbed, with six tiny eyes
> set all around its body. A wicked set of mandibles clacked visibly, while two long, fine antennae wove patterns in the air. Antennae, mandibles, eyes, and legs were sooty black, but the dominant color was the burnt orange of its armor plating.
>
> <sub>*(416 caracteres)*</sub>

Este relato corto está por supuesto traducido al español (se puede encontrar entre otras antologías en "*Canciones que Cantan los Muertos*").

Mi propuesta de traducción<sup>1</sup> contiene **469 caracteres**.

> Los Reyes de la Arena
>
>
>     La mujer señaló las criaturas que bullían en torno al castillo más cercano. Una de ellas estaba rascando la pared del tanque. Kress la examinó. A sus ojos, seguía teniendo el aspecto de un insecto. Apenas tan larga como una uña, con seis patas y seis ojos diminutos dispuestos en torno a su cuerpo. Un desagradable juego de mandíbulas se abría y cerraba visiblemente, mientras dos largas y delicadas antenas trazaban figuras en el aire. Antenas, mandíbulas, ojos y patas estaban ennegrecidos, pero el color dominante era el naranja encendido de su blindaje.

---

Recordad que [las normas](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2591/5481), para cualquier consulta, están en meta. Para cualquier otra cosa dejad un comentario. Recordad además que aparte de buscar la traducción con menor número de caracteres, queremos conservar el sentido. La descripción del *bichito* se las trae en este caso... pero creo que eso puede servir para lucirse y darle mucho juego a esta partida de translation golf.

*Sandkings* ha sido traducido de diversas formas. Hay una obvia y otras más creativas. He querido incluirlo como parte del texto (y como reto adicional), para ver qué se os ocurre.

Que os divirtáis.

---

Como ya han pasado un par de días y hay cuatro magníficas aportaciones, voy a compartir otra de las posibles traducciones "oficiales" que he visto para *Sandkings*, para comparar y estimular un poco más la partida con comentarios:

> Este relato corto de George R. R. Martin fue trasladado a la pequeña pantalla en un episodio piloto de la serie [*Más Allá del Límite*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%A1s_all%C3%A1_del_l%C3%ADmite) ([The Outer Limits](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Outer_Limits)). Tanto en España como en hispanoamérica se tituló de la misma manera: [Los arenícolas](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Los_aren%C3%ADcolas).

Viendo esa tradución, he de decir que las propuestas en este juego (Sultanes, Psamófilos) no tienen nada que envidiar en cuanto a creatividad.

---

### Fin de la partida

**Ganador** [**walen** con 235 caracteres](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/20876/5481)

Enhorabuena a todos, por una partida tan emocionante, tal despliegue de creatividad y deportividad (al evitar usar lo que otros jugadores ya habían usado y pese a todo, encontrar soluciones brillantes para acortar la traducción). Con cuatro o cinco ediciones cada uno, cada vez con un usuario nuevo poniéndose en cabeza o recuperando terreno, esta partida me ha recordado a [esta legendaria final de baloncesto](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XtyL1ZefbrI). **¡Bien jugado!**

@walen, recuerda que tienes un par de días para proponer un nuevo reto, si lo quieres empezar tú. No es una obligación.

---

<sub>**1**. Descargo de responsabilidad: aporto la traducción de acuerdo a las normas, pero no es mía, sino la traducción  de un editor/traductor profesional para este relato al español (o una de ellas). Así espero evitar también cierto sesgo en cuanto a hacer una traducción fiel al original (nadie más interesado en ello que el propio editor/traductor comercial de esta obra).</sub>

Comment: Entiendo que Jala Wo es un personaje femenino, ¿no? Por otra parte, tengo la duda de siempre: frases del tipo _One was scrabbling at the tank wall. Kress studied it._ pueden juntarse fácilmente, pero no sé si es válido. Mantiene el sentido, reduce el número de palabras pero, ¿lo aceptamos?

Comment: Sí, Wo es un personaje femenino. Y esas dos frases pueden juntarse (siempre que se mantenga el significado). Creo que si no le quitamos gracia a lo de minimizar número de caracteres

Comment: Yuck.  Very fun.  How do you find these fun quotes?

Comment: Me está encantado esta edición del juego, debo decirlo. Creo que está siendo con diferencia la más reñida y disputada hasta ahora, gracias a las increíbles aportaciones de walen y aparente. He leído tu nuevo 
spoiler y debo decir también que estuve a punto de llegar a esa misma traducción sin haberla leído, dado que estuve buscando un sufijo por el DLE que significara "que habita en", pero no llegó a ocurrírseme el de la traducción oficial. Y mira que era fácil, ahora que lo pienso...

Comment: Y tenemos que darle crédito también a Diego por encontrar un buen texto para el juego. // @walen - Buena idea, para el final del partido.  Yo reuní varios elementos al final de mi ronda, para satisfacerme propiamente más que nada, a ver si el formato te parece adecuado: https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/20783/9385

Comment: Viendo la hora a la que fue creada la pregunta (asked May 10 at 11:49), y dando una semana de plazo, creo que termina hoy miércoles 17 alrededor de las 12:00pm UTC. Como me pillará trabajando no puedo ser muy "estricto" a la hora de "cerrar" la partida. Pero sí, termina hoy en algún momento del día.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### <strike>297</strike> <strike>274</strike> <strike>271</strike> <strike>255</strike> 235 caracteres

> **Sultanes**
>
> "Ve los colores", señaló Wo la colonia del
> fuerte más a mano. Kress vio un... ¿insecto? rascar la pared del tanque. Seis patas, seis ojitos en un
> cuerpo de una uña. Fieras mandíbulas chascaban. Cual hilos, dos antenas
> tejían el aire. Apéndices, ojos tono tizón;
> regía el ocre dorado de su coraza.

He puesto "sultanes" porque, en la novela original, *sandkings* no es más que el nombre que le dan al bicho. Puestos a elegir un nombre en español, me parece que "sultanes" es más realista como nombre para unos escarabajos, al tiempo que mantiene las connotaciones del nombre original (ambos te hacen pensar en el desierto y en el poder).

Respecto a *wicked*, lo he traducido como "fiera" siguiendo [la segunda acepción del diccionario Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/wicked).

**Segunda versión**

- Cambio "dominaba" por "reinaba". "Ganaba" o "vencía" me ahorrarían otra letra maś, pero "reinar" le da más empaque a la frase :P -1.
- Elimino el "de" en "<strike>de</strike> color tizón", es relativamente habitual hacerlo en expresiones así: "miró al cielo color azul". -2.
- Pluralizo el primer "mandíbulas", ya que en los invertebrados las mandíbulas son cada una de las piezas de la boca, y para chascarlas hacen falta como mínimo dos :( Pero cambio el segundo "mandíbulas" por "boca" toda vez que ya sabemos a qué nos referimos :) -3.
- Cambio "los seres que pululaban por el castillo" por "el enjambre del castillo". En el original dice "*creatures that **swarmed***", y *swarm* como sustantivo significa literalmente "enjambre". -12.
- Reorganizo las frases del insecto rascando y Kress mirándolo. Me gustaba el orden original, pero aquí se viene a jugar :D -2.
- Cambio "cercano" por "más a mano". Pierdo un carácter, pero gano fidelidad al demostrativo original. +1.
- Fusiono el diálogo de Wo con su acción de señalar. Aplicando el mismo recurso que expresiones del tipo "-Cuidado al entrar-, señaló Gabriel el escalón". -2.

**Tercera versión**

- «Uno rascaba (...) Kress *lo* miró» => <strike>«Kress miró uno *que* rascaba (...)»</strike>  => «Kress miró: uno rascaba (...)». Usando «:» para indicar lo que veía Kress, puedo eliminar la subordinación introducida al cambiar el orden, y por tanto el «que». -3.

**Cuarta versión**

- Cambio "y dos largas, finas antenas" por "cual hilos, dos antenas". -3.
- Fusiono la descripción del largo con la descripción del cuerpo, aprovechando además que "cuerpo" también quiere decir "tamaño". -6.
- Añado puntos suspensivos en medio de "un... ¿insecto?" para transmitir mejor (espero) el concepto de "a Kress le seguía pareciendo un insecto y, aunque no lo fuera, tampoco tenía un nombre mejor". +0.
- Cambio "castillo" por "fuerte". -2.
- Cambio "el naranja fuego" por "el arcilla". Como color es muy parecido al naranja tostado (más que el naranja fuego, seguro); y puedo hacer elipsis de "color" sin problema al estar claro que "el" (masculino) no se refiere a "arcilla" (femenino). -5.
- Aún se puede reducir más si quito de en medio la "visibilidad" del chasquido, o si cambio las partes por el todo en la enumeración final. Aunque ya se ha hecho algo similar en otras traducciones, son cambios que veo algo drásticos y que me reservo para caso de necesidad.

**Quinta versión**

- «Enjambre» por «colonia». -1.
- «miró: un insecto rascaba» por «vio un insecto rascar». -2.
- «cuerpo menor que su uña» por «cuerpo de una uña». No solo es más corto en letras, sino más fiel al tamaño de la descripción original. -5.
- «Veía sus fieras mandíbulas chascar» por «Fieras mandíbulas chascaban». Obviamente lo veía, si no no lo estaría describiendo. -5.
- «Antenas, boca, ojos, patas» por «Apéndices, ojos». -7.
- «color» por «tono». -1.
- «arcilla» por «ocre dorado». +3.
- «reinaba» por «regía». -2.

---

**Nota: sobre los colores**

En esta y otras entradas se ha estado debatiendo sobre la tonalidad de los bichos, y se han planteado varios colores con distintos grados de aceptación según quien leyese. La clave aquí, creo, es que no todos pensamos en el mismo color cuando leemos una palabra.
Por ejemplo, lo que para mí es [color arcilla](https://www.pantone.com/color-finder/PQ-18-1340TCX), puede no tener nada que ver con lo que para otra persona es [color arcilla](https://www.pantone.com/color-finder/PQ-15-1231TCX).
Si os parece, como referencia podemos usar la guía PANTONE, que es el estándar usado en diseño e industria. Los colores que he visto como mas próximos son:

- [Burnt Orange / naranja tostado](https://www.pantone.com/color-finder/PQ-16-1448TCX)
- [Rust / óxido](https://www.pantone.com/color-finder/PQ-18-1248TCX)
- [Clay / arcilla / y entiendo que "teja"](https://www.pantone.com/color-finder/PQ-18-1340TCX)
- [Copper / cobrizo](https://www.pantone.com/color-finder/PQ-16-1325TCX)
- [Golden Ochre / ocre dorado](https://www.pantone.com/color-finder/PQ-16-1346TCX)
- [Raw Sienna / siena](https://www.pantone.com/color-finder/PQ-17-1436TCX)
- [Orange Ochre / naranja ocre](https://www.pantone.com/color-finder/PQ-16-1253TCX)

Por mi parte podéis usarlos en vuestras entradas, da igual quién los haya buscado.

Comment: Madre mía, acabas de romper la banca.

Comment: Cómo ha molado lo de "sultanes", mi enhorabuena.

Comment: Me quito el sombrero. Qué contribución más genial. Como "dungeon master" de esta partida, no me opongo a "*sultanes*". Me parece que lo fuerza un poco (desde luego es una traducción menos rigurosa que la más obvia de "reyes de la arena"), pero me parece tan creativo que prefiero premiarlo a penalizarlo, pues esto es lo que le da aliciente al juego.

Comment: I love it and "Sultanes" works great for me.  I personally think the "if you will" should not be omitted, although I'm not the judge!  "Mira" or "Nota" would be better in a published book, but I suppose in the game things are different.  When I was doing mine I went back and forth on whether "tejían el aire" was really equivalent and decided not; but your whole paragraph is so good I am now convinced that "figuras" isn't needed.  Your entry isn't just succinct, it also flows beautifully.

Comment: I really go for *reinar* and *enjambre*.  The *boca* trick seems acceptable to me personally, although strictly speaking, in an insect, the mouth parts are so much more than a mouth....  Removing *de* from *color tizón* is clever, as is the fusion in the first sentence.  Now I will nitpick a bit.  Thumbs down on "miró ¿un insecto? que rascaba."  This implies he is wondering if the creature is an insect, but the original says the creature still seemed like an insect to him -- not the same thing.  I do think a correction should be made in the ...

Comment: ... enjambre section: "señaló Wo el enjambre *en el* castillo más a mano."  This will convey more clearly that there is a swarm of something (we don't know what yet) *on* the castle.  Otherwise, the author might be saying that the castle looked somehow similar to a swarm of something (such as midges or mosquitos).

Comment: I'd recommend a capital U for your latest refinement: *Kress miró: Un ¿insecto? rascaba la pared del tanque. (I personally am still having trouble swallowing "¿insecto?")

Comment: Madre mía qué cara se va a vender la victoria esta vez... :-D

Comment: I'll explain my thinking about the colon.  At least in English, a colon can introduce a continuation of the sentence, but it can also introduce a separate sentence.  I think in this case, a separate sentence would be preferable because otherwise, we'd have "Kress miró un insecto."  I think it would be better to have an undefined object of his looking.  I hope I'm explaining this clearly.

Comment: "reinaba el arcilla de su coraza" - brilliant. // There is a small drawback of *arcilla* and *teja*, though.  Colors are more than just the hue.  There's also how much light the color reflects, and then there are connotations that are suggested.  From the original, I got a shiny, metallic feel.  And/or something sort of fiery looking.  Unfortunately, *arcilla* and *teja* are matte, while *burnt orange* (and, hopefully, *óxido*) are more metallic and in-your-face.  (Just some thoughts.)

Comment: Teclado: Have you tried "U.S. International"?  I can tell you how to install it if you like.

Comment: He leido tu entrada y las revisiones de las versiones y no creo que haya nada contras las normas. Personalmente el uso de "arcilla" me gusta menos (y tiene el mismo numero de letras que _naranja_, que conservaria el significado incluso mejor). Comparto el apunte de aparente001. Medir el numero de caracteres es muy objetivo. Medir que conserva el significado puede ser completamente subjetivo. Si no se te ocurre nada mejor, prefuiero "naranja" que "arcilla". Mismas letras, pero mantiene mejor. Por el resto, no tengo queja. Una entrada excelente con ideas brillantes.

Comment: Les doy un vistazo y le pondré un comentario a cada uno si hace falta. Pero es el problema que te decía antes con la subjetividad al evaluar la traducción en sí. No quiero andar con una "_checklist_" en plan (**wicked** set of mandibles: check; **Barely** as long: check...") y solo me meto si algo es muy evidente. Para cualquier cosa "anotadme" en un comentario y arbitro cualquier disputa o duda. Estaré más pendiente ante los cambios, para no tener que decirle a nadie que algo "no vale" justo cuando termine el plazo de la partida.

Comment: Could you please put a semicolon after "seis patas"? // "De una uña" is great -- I kept almost getting that and it's satisfying to see it work. // I do miss "enjambre." // "Visibly": removing it because of logical considerations is perhaps too much of a rewrite. // What would you say to "Apéndices, ojos: tizón; pero regía el naranja de su coraza." // I don't think "naranja" by itself is right. I think you had something better in an early version, don't remember what. These critters don't seem to have the color of an orange. They need something zingier, less neon. // I love regía and apéndices.

Comment: The dot dot dot is ingenious.  I can swallow "¿insecto?" now.

Comment: Well, there's always the garden variety period.  I would like a period there better than a comma but you get to decide. // Ocre dorado is another stroke of genius.  Very evocative.

Answer (score 3):

#### <s>351, 326, 288</s> 283 caracteres

> Reyes arenosos
>
> Wo: "Mira los tonos"— y señaló los bichos apiñados redor del tanque. Kress estudió uno; cavaba en el muro del tanque, le pareció un insecto. Largo cual uña, con seis patas y seis ojitos, malvadas mandíbulas claqueteantes y dos largas y finas antenas tejiendo en el aire. Todo, de negro tiznado; y, dominante, el naranja quemado de su caparazón.

- traduzco [wicked](http://www.wordreference.com/es/translation.asp?tranword=wicked) como <s>*pícara*, si bien por contexto puede que su acepción más adecuada sea la de</s> *malvada*.
- traduzco [sooty](http://www.wordreference.com/es/translation.asp?tranword=sooty) como *tiznado*, como si estuviera recubierto de hollín.
- [*redor*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=VZhUYLS) es sinónimo de *alrededor*.
- omito la repetición de las partes del cuerpo en la frase final.
- uso *tonos* como sinónimo de *colores*.
- hago caer el *dispuestos sobre su cuerpo* por obvio. Con "seis patas y seis ojitos" considero que ya se entiende la frase.
- Paso del modo explícito *"Fíjate en los colores", le dijo Wo* al implícito y teatral *Wo: "Mira los tonos"—*.
- Utilizo *cavar* en lugar de *escarbar* para decir "scrabbling". Hay [muchos sinónimos](http://www.wordreference.com/sinonimos/escarbar), este es el más corto...
- Recupero *tanque* en lugar de *castillo*. Ignoro por qué usé la palabra larga en un principio.
- Uso *Todo, de negro tiznado; y, dominante, el naranja quemado de su caparazón*. El *dominante* entre comas enfatiza que ese naranja es el que destaca.

Comment: Lots of great stuff here but I would not accept "los bichos alrededor del castillo" as conveying "swarming"; "pícara" doesn't sound right. // I took a course in entomology years ago and what I remember is that "mouth parts" -- "mandíbulas" -- are definitely plural.  So the "mandíbula claqueteante" should be plural. // What happened to "if you will" and "patterns"? // On the plus side, some of my favorite things: Fíjate, the rearranging in your Sentence #3, mas dominaba, caparazón (I like that word).

Comment: @aparente001 thanks for the ideas and corrections! // It is difficult to translate _swarming_ with no so many characters, so I tried with _apiñados redor_... // _tejían en el aire_ to me has the sense of _wove patterns in the air_. Does it make sense? // Mandíbula can be singular, but you are right in the sense that it is a combination of them, so plural is the correct one. // Do you really think it is necessary to translate "it you will"? Seems redundant to me.

Comment: Ya por curiosidad, ¿se puede decir "redor del castillo"? ¿O debe ser "en redor del castillo"? La entrada dice que "en redor" es la locución adverbial que equivale a "alrededor", pero igual me equivoco...

Comment: @CarlosAlejo pensé que _redor_ a secas es válido porque la primera acepción lo menciona como sinónimo de _alrededor_. Pero puedo estar equivocado.

Comment: Great alliteration in *malvadas mandíbulas*.

Comment: "Todo ello de negro tiznado" (omitting the listing of the black bits) is inspired.

Answer (score 3):

#### <strike>344 317 295 269</strike> 248 caracteres

> **Psamófilos**
>
> —Vea los colores—, pidió Wo. Señaló la nube de seres en el fortín cercano. Kress vio uno rayando la pared del tanque: aún le era un bicho. Medía casi su uña. Seis patas, seis ojitos dispersos, temibles quijales batiendo y dos filiformes antenas urdiendo el aire: negruzcas motas en su armazón cobrizo.

Comentarios:

- Rayar: "Estropear o deteriorar una superficie lisa o pulida con rayas o incisiones."
- Batir: "Mover con ímpetu y fuerza algo." Usado como en la expresión "reírse a mandíbula batiente".
- Uso un estilo literario abreviado para describir al bicho, ahorrando verbos: *[Tenía] seis patas*, *[Las] patas [eran] de [color] negro tizón*. Aún así, las frases mantienen su sentido.
- Estoy intentando inventarme algo más colorista para *sandkings*, pero de momento la versión obvia me parece muy elegante.

Primera actualización:

- "Vea" por "mire".
- "Fortín" por "castillo".
- Fusiono "Kress lo observó" con la siguiente frase. "Kress notó que aún le era un bicho." Al usar "notó" se implica que lo ha examinado.
- Cambio "parecía" por "le era", en el sentido de "era para él". Ejemplos en el CORDE: *Gaspar Luiz le era un constante ejemplo.* [="era para él"]
- "Hexápodo" por "seis patas".
- "Tejían formas" por "[urdían](http://dle.rae.es/?id=b8thAP5)" (transitivo, significando "preparar los hilos en la urdidera para pasarlos al telar"). Se mantiene el símil tejedor.
- "Mandíbulas" por "[quijales](http://dle.rae.es/?id=UqQuAB5)" ("cada una de las dos mandíbulas").
- "Largas y finas" por "[filiformes](http://dle.rae.es/?id=HurkUSP)" ("con forma de hilo"). A fin de cuentas, las antenas tienen forma de hilo al ser largas y delgadas.
- Reconstruida la última frase. Al usar "[motear](http://dle.rae.es/?id=PvetWps)" ("salpicar de motas una tela, para darle variedad y hermosura") se entiende que el color predominante es el naranja, y que lo negro son como motas ("manchas pequeñas"). El bicho no es una tela, pero me permito el uso como licencia literaria.
- Encontrada la versión más colorista para los "reyes de la arena" gracias a [esta respuesta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/20878/12637). En botánica se denomina *[psamófilas](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psam%C3%B3fila)* a las plantas que se han adaptado a vivir en la arena. Viene del griego *psammos* ("arena") y *‒́filo* ("amante de"). Así, se toma el concepto de "rey" como el de "persona, animal o cosa que por su excelencia sobresalen entre los demás de su clase o especie", y se considera con este nombre que los bichos son los mejores adaptados a la arena (los reyes en la arena).

Segunda actualización:

- Se reescriben las últimas frases para evitar la repetición de todas las partes que motean de negro el cuerpo. Se ahorra así bastante espacio, pero he tenido que renunciar a lo de "hexápodo" (con lo que me gustaba).
- "Apenas" por "casi".
- Se entiende que los ojos están en su cuerpo, lo interesante es lo de "all around", que se traduce por "dispersos".
- Según la Wikipedia en inglés, el color *burnt orange* es el hexadecimal `#BF5700`, que es [este](http://html-color.org/es/BF5700). Yo no sé a vosotros, pero a mí me parece más marrón que naranja, así que he puesto "marronáceo". Esta palabra no viene en el DLE, pero sí viene el sufijo *[-áceo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=0NLwOnV)* ("semejante a").
- He tenido que renunciar también a esa primera frase que me gustaba, introduciendo la invitación cambiando "dijo" por "pidió".
- Cambio "blindaje" por "[armazón](http://dle.rae.es/?id=3arnyx0)", que según el DLE es equivalente a "armadura" en su sentido de "esqueleto".

Tercera actualización:

- Por sugerencia de aparente, cambio "marronáceo" por "color teja", el cual da la misma sensación de [tono marrón anaranjado](https://www.google.es/search?q=color%20teja) que el "burnt orange".

Cuarta actualización:

- El color cobrizo también tiene un tono naranja tostado marronáceo y además da la sensación de metálico.
- Cambio "sobre el fortín" por "en el fortín".
- Uso de "medir". Generalmente si no se especifica nada, lo que se mide es el largo entendiéndose como la dimensión predominante.
- Se reescribe la última frase, manteniendo la idea de que las partes del cuerpo son "motas" ("mancha, pinta o dibujo redondeado o muy pequeño") de negro en su armazón. (Gracias a fedorqui por la idea de los dos puntos.)
- Fusión de frases.

Comment: Excelente aportación. Una manera muy ingeniosa de traducir la primera frase. Me encanta el uso de "seres". No sé cuánto tiempo deberíamos tener abierta esta partida. Una semana como siempre? Avisadme si queréis una pista para _sandkings_. La otra versión que conozco para el nombre hace un poco de trampa, a pesar de ser "oficial".

Comment: Great stuff here too.  One quibble: "mas el naranja tostado dominaba su blindaje" doesn't seem right.  The burnt orange **of the armor plating** dominated, so: *mas el naranja tostado de su blindaje dominaba*. // I really like the *nube* and *terribles*.  // Problem with *batían*: there's no sound!

Comment: @aparente001 he arreglado lo del blindaje (gracias), y sobre que el verbo no implique sonido: en la traducción propuesta por el OP tampoco se infiere sonido, luego no debería haber problema.

Comment: @Diego si quieres darnos una pista, puedes probar a responder [esta pregunta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/20873/12637) que he hecho en el sitio. :-)

Comment: "clacked": onomotopeia.  http://www.thefreedictionary.com/clack // It's not the blindaje that dominates, it's the color of the blindaje that dominates.  (My personal opinion.)

Comment: @aparente001 entiendo tu postura, sé que _clacked_ implica un sonido. Lo que quería decir era que si Diego se ha tomado la libertad de proponer una traducción que no implica un sonido, yo también puedo hacerlo. :-) || Sobre el blindaje: al darle un color al blindaje en realidad se entiende que es dicho color el que domina, no el blindaje en sí.

Comment: Yo pienso que hay que ser fiel al texto, no a la interpretación del que lo propuso, pero quizás sería buena idea aclarar las reglas. // To do a great job translating, one needs to fully understand the meaning of the original text.  That's part of the exercise, I think.  So I don't think you get to inherit Diego's slip.  Also, I see the OP's translation as protection against people trying to get free translations from the site, more than anything else.  Or something like a control subject in an experiment.

Comment: @aparente001 The rules state that the OP has the last word in case of doubt. I think that _batían_ is a very minor license. Besides, I really doubt that the mandibles of such a tiny creature produce any sound. Have you ever heard an ant's mandibles? I think that the use of _clacked_ is more to note that the mandibles moved violently, and that's why the author uses _visibly_ after the verb: you were able to _see_ them move, but not actually _hear_ them.

Comment: I thought the clacking was audible because these creatures were metallic.  But you won't catch me reading the book to check if that's right!  I read a bit at Wikipedia.  Yuck!

Comment: @aparente001, Para arbitrar sobre este asunto, he añadido el disclaimer. La traducción no es realmente mía, si no la traducción el español de este relato (realizada posiblemente por un traductor profesional). En cualquier caso no veo problema en "batir" (como en el _batir_ de las alas de una mariposa). Brillante ese "hexápodo", por cierto.

Comment: Fortín and hexápodo are inspired.  I like this turn of phrase: "apenas su uña de largo."  But now I want to know how to pronounce Psamófilos!  Do I ignore the P?

Comment: @aparente001 that could be a nice question for the site, if it has not been already asked yet. ;-)

Comment: @aparente001 from [DPD on _p_](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=KKIXcZ6vMD6UiQB0EW) _se admite en la escritura la reducción del grupo ps- a s-, grafía que refleja mejor la pronunciación normal de las palabras que contienen este grupo inicial, en las que la p- no suele articularse_. Así que de hecho Carlos podrías usar _samófilos_.

Comment: @fedorqui es que me mola cómo queda con _p_, pero lo haré si no me queda más remedio. :-)

Comment: (I haven't looked at the others' edits yet but I need to nitpick here a bit.) I'd like to see a link showing that *quijales* is actually used when talking about insects.  I took an entomology course in Mexico and never saw *quijales*.  I wouldn't want you to just pluck a word from the dictionary without confirming its usage in the context. // Sorry, but thumbs down from one person on *urdir* and *motear*.  Preparing the warp threads is a far cry from actually weaving patterns.  Analogy: laying railroad track is different from traveling by express train.  *Motear* is a nice word, but doesn't...

Comment: ... fit here except for the six eyes dotting the body.  I take the armor plating to be similar to the wing cases of a beetle.  Except for the eyes, the soot black parts of the sand king are all at the mouth end and the skinny bits. // Suggestions: You could reduce by two letters if you took out the P in *psamófilos* and switched to informal in the quote. // Not sure, but perhaps you could remove the article: "aún le era bicho." // You could switch *apenas* for *casi*: "casi su uña de largo" (I like what you did with *su*).

Comment: I wonder if you could use *redor* which fedorqui used elsewhere: "seis ojitos redor"?

Comment: How about putting a semi-colon after *batiendo*?  That sentence is starting to look like German. // Because I like you and I can tell that you are avoiding using "óxido" because I already did, I will make a suggestion to replace marronáceo: *teja*.  I haven't thought yet about whether one would need to say *color teja* -- I'll let you think about that.  But you are welcome to stick with *marronáceo* if you like that better. // Note, I didn't get down to the level of hex color numbers -- I was just eyeballing them.  See what you think of *teja*.

Comment: @aparente001 According to the DLE, you can use just "teja" for "color teja". Nonetheless, "armazón teja" does not sound to me as you were specifying a color, so I could go for "armazón color teja" that only saves 1 character. But it is sincerely a very good suggestion, as the colors are quite similar indeed. You are right, I don't want to use "óxido" because it's your idea. Sportmanship is always a non-written rule I try to follow. About the semicolon: that would render the last sentence "A, B, C; y D moteaban" that doesn't seem right to me.

Comment: @walen de hecho acabo de reestructurar toda la segunda mitad y he acabado poniendo un punto tras "uña". Y he dejado libre "teja" por si quieres usarlo. :-)

Comment: ¿Y dos puntos para cargarte el _eran_ de "eran negruzcas..."? _Seis patas, seis ojitos dispersos, temibles quijales batiendo y dos filiformes antenas urdiendo el aire: negruzcas motas en su armazón cobrizo._

Comment: The end is really very satisfying (the fusion).  Also *cobrizo* is the perfect word for the color.  Metallic! // "Medía" is great.  Another one of those words I wondered whether I could use, and *almost* solved -- and then you did.  It's a relief to see that yes, after all, it does work. // I think we need a separate Question about the word "bicho."  When is it an insect and when is it more general than *insect*.  Note you and I are taking different meanings from it.

Comment: What I find a bit fuzzy is when is a *bicho* an insect and when is it something broader?  Garrapata, pulga, arañita -- to me, these are loosely speaking *bichos* but they aren't insects.  It seems like one of those words that doesn't have a precise meaning.  I suppose in Carlos's translation, I could take *bicho* to mean something organic -- sorry I didn't realize that earlier, Carlos.

Answer (score 3):

Version 4.

#### <strike>346</strike> <strike>273</strike> <strike>270</strike> 280

> Reyes de Arena
>
> "Nota los colores, por favor." Wo apuntó el primer castel tapizado de bichos. Kress miró uno, cuasi insecto.  Rascaba por salir del tanque. Tamaño de uña, hexápodo, seis ojitos redor del cuerpo.  Mandíbulas crueles cerrando ¡crac!  Esbeltas antenas trazando figuras en el aire. Armadura: óxido; miembros y ojos: hollín.

Notes

- Sentence 2: I changed the focal point (primary object) from the creatures to the castle because I don't think it matters; the critters still catch the reader's attention.  (Was able to save a couple of characters by doing so.)
- "Bichos" -- to me this means *critters*; hopefully this will work.

A total squash job!

Notes for Version 2:

- "if you will" is expressed through "invitó."
- "Apuntó" will hopefully be understood as *pointed out*.
- I fished in DRAE and found *castel* which is supposedly a synonym for *castillo*.
- I think the "scrabbling at the tank wall" was due to a critter trying to get out.
- With "cuasi insecto" I am hopefully conveying Kress's opinion or judgment about a similarity.
- "Menudo" is intended to convey a miniscule size.
- I looked up the colors in Google Images and rust-colored looked the same to me as burnt orange.

Notes for Version 4:

- I really don't know why I removed tapizado earlier but I have restored it.  Nice word.
- Moved "cuasi insecto" hoping to respond to Diego's comment.  I am rather attached to "cuasi."
- Went for a parallel construction (*cerrando, trazando*).
- Experimenting with new way of comparing the colors.

I nitpicked the heck out of everybody else -- now please let me know what is not working about this entry.

Comment: I find interesting and educative the usage of _segundaba_. I am familiar with _secundar_, which has another meaning, but did not know about this one. I had to check it in DRAE to confirm its meaning and I have to say it is not common at all in normal speaking!

Comment: @fedorqui - I confess, I fished for it.  Recently, Carlos taught me how to troll for words alphabetically in the DRAE.

Comment: I cannot say much about this entry, except for congratulations! I took some literary licenses in my translation as you have seen, so I will not nitpick yours. Just point that "menudas" should be plural as it refers to "patas", and the "figuras en el aire" sentence looks like the antennae were the figures in the air, and not that they moved creating figures in the air.

Comment: @CarlosAlejo - Oops, I meant *menudo* (referring to *cuasi insecto*).  My idea with the antennas was to make a parallel construction with the previous phrase, through the use of the colon.  Does that explanation make it hold water better?

Comment: OK, so you just changed the fingernail comparison with just "menudo". The problem with that is that "menudo" is a relative word. I can be "una persona menuda" if you compare me with Pau Gasol, but I'm considered a tall person. So with "menudo" you don't really get the exact size of the creature as you got with the comparison. As for the antennae, I understood what you were trying to do with the two sentences, but the first thing that came to my mind when reading that is that the antennae were the forms in the air. I'm not asking you to change that, it's just my opinion.

Comment: I will do some editing tonight or tomorrow.  My letter count will be going up as I do some fixing.

Comment: En vez de "**con tapiz** de bichos" por qué no "tapizado". Mismas letras y conserva mejor el significado. Ese "Cuasi insecto" chirría un poco. Puede ser muchas cosas. En el original a Kress _le parece_ un insecto. El uso de "óxido" es genial, aunque se pierde un poco con esa sintaxis. Qué tal "Armadura de color óxido; hollín en miembros y ojos"? (va una letra de diferencia, lo sé :-(, pero es que la sintaxis chirría un poco).

Answer (score 0):

#### Fuera de concurso: 211 caracteres.

> Sultanes
>
> "Ve los tonos", pidió Wo. Señaló la colonia del primer fortín. Kress vio un... ¿insecto? rayar el muro del tanque. Tamaño de uña. Seis patas, seis ojitos dispersos, fieros quijales batiendo y dos esbeltas antenas tejiendo el aire: motas tizón en su coraza óxido.

Esta entrada está hecha uniendo las mejores ideas que, en mi opinión, hemos aportado cada uno por separado. ¡Insuperable!