# ¿Existe algún afijo que signifique "arena" o "hecho de arena"?

Tags: significado, solicitud-de-término, palabras-raras, prefijos

Vamos a hacer que las preguntas de [translation-golf](/questions/tagged/translation-golf) sirvan para algo más que para jugar.

En la [actual edición del juego](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/20863/12637) se pregunta por la traducción de *sandkings* (una especie de criatura pequeña). Aparte de su traducción obvia como "reyes de la arena", estoy buscando un nombre más colorido y para ello quería saber si existe en español algún afijo que signifique "arena" o "hecho de arena". Lo más cercano que he encontrado es:

> **[lito-, -lito](http://dle.rae.es/?id=NRayp6C)**
>
> Del gr. λίθος *líthos* 'piedra'.
>
> 1. elems. compos. Significa 'piedra', 'fósil'. *Litografía, litófago. Megalito, osteolito.*

Pues algo similar estoy buscando, pero para "arena". En el DLE no encuentro nada (que no quiere decir que no lo haya), pero estaba pensando tal vez en algún tratado de geología o similar, si existe alguna palabra con un elemento compositivo como el que busco, para usarlo también.

Posibles opciones son las palabras latinas *arena* y *sabula*. Desconozco cuál podría ser la palabra adecuada en griego antiguo.

Comment: Y por cierto, ¡hoy hago un año en [Spanish.SE]!

Comment: ¡Felicidades Carlos! Casi 20K en reputación repartido en más de una respuesta por día y una pregunta cada dos. Y, sobre todo, mucho trabajo del bueno. ¡Por muchos años más!

Comment: Enhorabuena por esa medalla "yearling". Bien merecida. Aparte de tus extraordinarias, increíblemente documentadas respuestas y tus ingeniosas preguntas, has sido promotor de otras brillantes iniciativas que han mejorado mucho este _stack_, como el [translation-golf](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2591/5481). Sin duda, uno de los mayores y mejores aportadores de esta comunidad.

Comment: @fedorqui muchas gracias, la verdad es que hacía tiempo que no me sentía tan integrado en un sitio. Y cuando he visto que llevo casi 400 respuestas no me lo creía ni yo. :-D

Comment: @Diego gracias a ti también, por tus comentarios que casi me hacen saltar la lagrimita. Mi objetivo era llegar a ser el primero en reputación del sitio antes de un año, pero tu despertar allá por diciembre me lo acabó poniendo imposible. :-D ¡Pero bienvenido sea tu despertar! Estás llenando el sitio de preguntas muy interesantes, que me hacen aprender español e inglés a partes iguales, así que lo mismo te digo, ¡a seguir así!

Comment: La verdad es que este pique sano le ha sentado muy bien al sitio. A veces me pregunto de dónde sacas tantas preguntas y seguro que el NTLLE te tiene como visitante número 1 :) Coincido con @Diego en que tu tesón ha ido ensanchando los límites de esta página para hacerla mucho mejor. ¡Gracias!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Psamo-** como en [psamófilo](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psam%C3%B3fila), de *psammos*, arena, y *filos*, amante, procedentes del griego.