# ¿Existe un nombre de animal que empiece por la letra "W"?

Tags: solicitud-de-término, letras, animales

Ayer, (re)leyendo uno de sus libros con mi hijo (una de esas historias en las que con cada letra del abecedario buscan un animal) me sorprendió que decía el libro que no habían podido encontrar ningún animal cuyo nombre empezara con la `w`, y que se lo inventaban.

¿No existe ningún nombre de animal en español que empiece por la letra `w`?

Comment: He pensado *wombat* pero parece que en español es *vombátido*

Comment: @blonfu *Vombátidos* es la familia zoológica a que pertenece el wombat (igual que nosotros somos homínidos).

Comment: @Gorpik Eso me parecía a mi pero en algunos diccionarios la traducción de *wombat* es *vombátido*. Quizá la especie y la familia tienen el mismo nombre en inglés

Comment: Por cierto ¿Qué animal inventaron para el libro?

Comment: Esto me hace pensar del guanaco de la region andina.  Dicen que el nombre viene del quechua wanaku.  Pero la manera de escribir palabras en quechua no es producto de los nativos, sino de los españoles.  Claro que en español no se escribe con w.  Pero es ejemplo del proceso que resulta en deletreos castellanos.

Comment: @blonfu el libro, el Abezoo de Carlos Reviejo y Javier Aramburu, se inventa "el **wansifeo** que tienes tres alas,/ patas de avestruz,/ cuello de jirafa,/ cola de caballo,/ cabeza de vaca/ y un cuerpo de cerdo,/ cubierto de escamas."

Comment: @blonfu La familia zoológica es *vombatidae*, que en castellano se suele adaptar a *vombátidos*. En inglés no suelen traducir los nombres de las familias. Simplemente *wombat* o *uómbat* es el nombre común de los vombátidos, aunque son muchas especies distintas.

Comment: @Gorpik Entonces no se porque lo traducen asi

Comment: @blonfu Ni idea, la verdad. Habría que ver el contexto. En un texto de zoología, lo habitual es usar el nombre zoológico (en este caso, vombátido); en otro caso, me parece un tanto pedante.

Comment: Por cierto, ¿qué libro es?

Comment: @jalazbe, el ["Abezoo" de Carlos Reviejo y Javier Aramburu](https://darabuc.wordpress.com/2007/09/17/abezoo-de-carlos-reviejo-y-javier-aramburu/). De hecho en ese enlace viene la entrada para la `w` del libro...

Comment: Gracias @Diego, me puede ser útil como regalo.

Comment: @walen es verdad. Se me ocurre que en los idiomas de los aborígenes australianos haya muchos nombres de animales que empiecen por un sonido similar  a la *w* en inglés y se transcribieran así.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Hay que tener en cuenta que [la letra W no entró a formar parte del alfabeto español hasta hace apenas 50 años](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/21079/13628), mientras que la inmensa mayoría de los nombres de animales en español son muy anteriores a eso. Salvo que haya sido descubierto en el último medio siglo, cualquier nombre de animal que originalmente empezase por W habrá sufrido un proceso de castellanización para hacerlo empezar por B, V, o U.
Dicho lo cual...

#### Wallaby

En la RAE no aparece la palabra *wallaby*, pero tampoco aparece [*ualabí*](http://dle.rae.es/srv/search?w=ualab%C3%AD), que es como se supone que se dice en español (EDIT: ver nota al pie sobre esto). Así que, puestos a llamarlo de alguna manera, mejor hacerlo como en su tierra natal (al fin y al cabo, si escribimos [waterpolo](http://dle.rae.es/srv/search?w=waterpolo), no veo por qué no íbamos a escribir *wallaby*).

> Los ualabíes (del inglés *wallaby*) son marsupiales propios de Australia y de la isla de Nueva Guinea. Sus dimensiones son menores que las de los canguros, alcanzando 1,2 m de longitud, y un peso que ronda entre 1 kg (ualabí rupestre) a 42 kg.
>
> <sub>Fuente: [Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ualab%C3%AD)</sub>

[image]

---

**Nota sobre el uso de *wallaby* frente a *ualabí*.**
Indica Gorpik: *«Si buscas ualabí en Google te salen casi cien mil referencias. Es una grafía asentada en zoología»*. No lo discuto. También es cierto que, puestos a buscar en Google, si buscas "wallaby" filtrando por páginas en español, te salen más de cuatrocientas mil; y más de ciento sesenta mil para "walabí".
Por otra parte, preguntado NGRAM por [apariciones de "wallaby", "walabí", "ualabí" en el corpus de español](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=wallaby%2C+walab%C3%AD%2C+ualab%C3%AD&year_start=1800&year_end=2017&corpus=21&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwallaby%3B%2Cc0), dice que solo aparece el primero. Incluso el CREA de la RAE saca una coincidencia para "wallaby" pero ninguna para "ualabí" ni para "walabí".
Sin perjuicio de *ualabí*, creo que *wallaby* es una forma suficientemente extendida en español.

Comment: Si buscas *ualabí* en Google te salen casi cien mil referencias. Es una grafía asentada en zoología.

Comment: Voy a marcar esta respuesta como la aceptada. Las otras son también muy buenas y muy válidas, pero esta se distingue por la explicación inicial acerca de la `W`.

Answer (score 11):

**WOMBAT**

En la RAE no aparece la palabra "Wombat" ni tampoco "Vombátido". A efectos prácticos no he encontrado forma de llamar a este animal si no es usando su nombre original "Wombat" o "Uombat". El la mayoría de los casos se refiere a este animal utilizando la W.

> Los vombátidos (Vombatidae) son una familia de marsupiales
>   diprotodontos, conocidos comúnmente como wombats o uómbats. Se
>   encuentran solo en Australia, incluida Tasmania, y tienen la
>   apariencia de un oso musculado, pequeño y de patas muy cortas.
>   Actualmente existen tres especies de wombats con vida, todas las
>   cuales miden alrededor de un metro y pesan entre 20 y 35 kg. Su color
>   de piel varía del beige al marrón y del negro al grís. [Wiki](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vombatidae)

[image]

Comment: That chubby little guy is so adorable

Answer (score 8):

De manera similar a lo que ocurre con las distintas grafías (ualabí / walabi) en la [respuesta de walen](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/21967/5481), y o he dado con otro animal, pero presenta los mismos "problemas".

El uapití o wapití (mejor conocido como **ciervo canadiense**) es

> es una especie de mamífero artiodáctilo de la familia de los cérvidos que vive en América del Norte, Asia central y oriental.
>
> Los primeros exploradores europeos de Norteamérica que no estaban familiarizados con esta especie los confundieron con los alces por su gran tamaño, lo que ha originado cierta confusión con el nombre de esta especie, porque los norteamericanos además de wapiti siguen llamándolo «elk», que en inglés británico significa alce, y a su vez llaman al alce «moose», por lo que a menudo se hacen traducciones incorrectas.
>
> La palabra «wapití» procede de la lengua shawnee y significa nalgas blancas, en referencia al color del escudo anal de estos animales.5​ Su nombre científico Cervus canadensis significa en latín ciervo canadiense, y hace referencia a donde fueron observados por primera vez por los colonos europeos.
>
> <sub>Fuente: [wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cervus_canadensis)</sub>

[image]

A pesar de no aparecer en el diccionario de la RAE bajo ninguna de estas dos entradas, hay múltiples referencias a estos animales en la red.

Comment: Este es el que más me gusta para tus fines.

Answer (score 6):

Subiéndome al carro (y considerando lo bajo que está nuestro ranking de respuestas por pregunta), agrego estos tres que no tienen ninguna ambigüedad con su ortografía, siempre comienzan con W, pero claramente no son palabras españolas:

> **[Walgettosuchus](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Walgettosuchus)**
>
> Walgettosuchus (“Cocodrilo de "Walgett"”) es un género representado por una única especie de dinosaurio terópodo tetanuro, que vivió a mediados del período Cretácico, hace aproximadamente 100 millones de años, en el Albiense.

[image: imagen Walgettosuchus]

> **[Wakinosaurus](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wakinosaurus)**
>
> Wakinosaurus (“lagarto de Wakino”) es un género representado por una única especie de dinosaurio terópodo carnosaurio, que vivió a finales del período Cretácico, hace aproximadamente entre 135 y 130 millones de años, durante el Hauteriviense y Barremiense, en lo que es hoy Asia.

[image: imagen wakinosaurus]

> **[Wuerhosaurus](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wuerhosaurus)**
>
> Wuerhosaurus ("reptil de Wuerho") es un género de dinosaurios tireóforos estegosáuridos, que vivieron a principios del período Cretácico, hace aproximadamente 135 y 99 millones de años, entre el Valanginiense y el Albiense), en lo que hoy es Asia.

[image: imagen wuerhosaurus]

Comment: +1. Aunque por un segundo pensé que me ibas a sorprender con alguna palabra del náhuatl o quechua.

Answer (score 6):

Al final vamos a tener mas animales que empiezan con w que con cualquier otra letra. Uno más:

**[Weta](https://es.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weta)**

> Los wetas son grandes ortópteros, nocturnos y ápteros originarios de
>   Nueva Zelanda. Algunos de ellos se encuentran entre los insectos más
>   grandes y pesados (el weta gigante (Deinacrida), por ejemplo) y se
>   cree que son especies muy antiguas, ya que se han hallado fósiles de
>   criaturas parecidas del Triásico, que vivieron hace 180-190 millones
>   de años en Queensland (Australia). Miden aproximadamente 10 cm.

[image]

Comment: +1. Eso no es un weta, para mí que eso es un de los [reyes de la arena](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/20863/5481)!! ;-p

Comment: @Diego - de acuerdo.  Fuchi.

Answer (score 5):

Acabo de encontrar otro, el **walaró**.

Hay incluso un [walaró antílope](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macropus_antilopinus):

> El walaró antílope (Macropus antilopinus) es una especie de marsupial diprotodonto de la familia de los Macropodidae, a veces llamado canguro antílope o walabí antílope, ya que es grande y se parece mucho más a un canguro que un walaró común. Habita en el norte de Australia, en la península de Cabo York en Queensland, el extremo del Territorio del Norte, y la región de Kimberley en Australia Occidental.

[image]

y un [walaró oriental o común](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macropus_robustus)

> El walaró oriental o común (Macropus robustus) es una especie de marsupial diprotodonto de la familia Macropodidae que habita en gran parte del continente australiano. Es una de los macrópodos más grandes y más comunes.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Además del ciervo y los marsupiales, el weta y los dinosaurios ya mencionados, hay:

### Peces

- Wallago
- Wara Wara

### Anfibios

- Wetlugasaurus

### Réptiles

- [Wishywilly](http://www.naturalista.mx/taxa/35307-Ctenosaura-oedirhina)
- [Wishiwilly del suampo](http://www.iucnredlist.org/details/44181/0)
- [Woma](http://laberintoenextincion.blogspot.co.uk/2009/10/piton-woma-aspidites-ramsayi.html) (tb. Pitón woma, Pitón de Ramsay)
- [Wualu](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=UHDWz6LkfYMC&pg=PA92&dq=Wualu)
- [Wayapopi [harra]](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=pVcgAQAAIAAJ&q=wayapopi)

### Mamíferos:

- Watusi (tb. Ankole-Watusi, Ankole)
- Wanderoo (tb. uanderú, sileno, macaco de cola de león, mono león, mono barbudo)
- **Marsupiales:**

  - Wongai ningaui
  - Wallaby de Bennet (tb. ualabí de cuello rojo, ualabí de Bennet)

### Dinosaurios:

- Wannanosaurus (*wananosaurio*)
- Wendiceratops
- Wiehenvenator
- Willinakaqe
- Wintonotitan
- Wulagasaurus
- Wulatelong

- Wadhurstia – sinónimo junior de Hypselospinus
- "Walkeria" – nombre preocupado, actualmente Alwalkeria
- "Walkersaurus" – *nomen nudum*; Duriavenator
- "Wangonisaurus" – *nomen nudum*, probablemente Giraffatitan
- "Wyomingraptor" – *nomen nudum*, probablemente alosaurio
- **Aves:**

  - Wellnhoferia – ave, posiblemente un sinónimo junior de Archaeopteryx
  - Wyleyia – probablemente un ave
- **Aves modernas:**

  - Wirapuru (tb. Wira-Purú, Vyra-Purú o Uirapuru)
  - Wonga (Paloma wonga)
  - Weka (Rascón weka)
  - [Wacamayo](https://tesoro.pr/lema/wacamayo) (tb. guacamayo, wacamaya, guacamaya)

---

<sup>• [https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anexo:Géneros_válidos_de_dinosaurios#W](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anexo:G%C3%A9neros_v%C3%A1lidos_de_dinosaurios#W)

 • [https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anexo:Géneros_dudosos_de_dinosaurios#W](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anexo:G%C3%A9neros_dudosos_de_dinosaurios#W)

 • [https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anexo:Géneros_sinónimos_de_dinosaurios#W](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anexo:G%C3%A9neros_sin%C3%B3nimos_de_dinosaurios#W)

 • [https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anexo:Géneros_inválidos_de_dinosaurios#W](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anexo:G%C3%A9neros_inv%C3%A1lidos_de_dinosaurios#W)

 • [https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anexo:Nombres_en_castellano_de_las_aves_del_mundo_recomendados_por_la_Sociedad_Española_de_Ornitología](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anexo:Nombres_en_castellano_de_las_aves_del_mundo_recomendados_por_la_Sociedad_Espa%C3%B1ola_de_Ornitolog%C3%ADa)</sup>

Comment: Wow - como hiciste para encontrarlos?