# Are there any words that start with "hua" that aren't derived from foreign languages, and if not, why not?

Tags: historia, ortografía

I can think of plenty of Spanish words derived from Quechua or other foreign languages that start with "hua", but not for Spanish words that are derived from earlier forms of Spanish such as vulgar Latin.

For example, if I look at the English Wiktionary for [Spanish terms derived from Latin](https://en.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=Category:Spanish_terms_derived_from_Latin&from=hu), there are 10310 total words, but none start with hua. By contrast, Wiktionary only lists 137 terms in [Spanish terms derived from Quechua](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:Spanish_terms_derived_from_Quechua), but has several words starting with "hua", including huaca (a relic in Inca culture), huacatay (a plant), and haurizo (a hybrid of a male llama and a female alpaca, sometimes called a [llapaca](https://www.alpacamagic.com.au/llapacas/) in English).

No words from Latin were hiding amongst spellings starting with [wa](https://en.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=Category:Spanish_terms_derived_from_Latin&from=wa), or [ua](https://en.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=Category:Spanish_terms_derived_from_Latin&from=ua), and none of the words starting with [gua](https://en.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=Category:Spanish_terms_derived_from_Latin&from=gu) looked like good candidates either.

Spanish has Latin-derived words starting with "hu" plus at least some other vowels. For example huevo, derived from Latin ōvum, and huir, derived from Latin fugere.

Are there any Spanish words that start with "hua" that aren't derived from foreign languages? If not, why not?

Related question: [Why is the letter 'w' reserved for words that are acquired from other languages?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/34557/why-is-the-letter-w-reserved-for-words-that-are-acquired-from-other-languages)

Comment: @今夜九  It’s the language that Spanish derived from. Do you have any suggestions on how to improve the terminology of my question?

Comment: This doesn't help with your question.  But a search on "cultura huanca" gives a trove of articles about a culture centered around Huancayo, Peru.  The Huancas reached their peak before the Quechas arose.

Answer (score 2):

Languages evolve through time thanks to many variables. You can't just simply pretend to ask why this language behaves this or that way. I'm a native speaker and I can't recall any word starting to hua. As you have done your research it seems as you mentioned, the words that exist are derivative from ancient foreign languages. It's what it is, and I bet, given the current trend, those words might be dropped from the dictionary at some point. New words are added, and old words are dismissed, that's how languages evolve.

Answer (score 1):

Lo cierto es que son cuestiones amplias que tienen cada una su propio desarrollo, y en algunos casos algunas son más complicadas que otras. Intentaré unificarlas, aunque no se si acertaré a que se entiendan.

---

Hasta donde sé, en la propia lengua latina, el latín, hay que matizar varias cuestiones que planteas y hay que entender previamente que; por una parte, en latín, las letras que comienzan por "h" son relativamente pocas. Esta "h" a veces y dependiendo de los lugares evolucionó hacia el sonido de "h" aspirada y la forma "j", letra que tampoco existía en el abecedario latino y que fue una alteración o alargamiento de la propia "i". A su vez, la "i" (semivocal) podía tomarse como vocal en el caso de "insula" o como consonante en el caso de "iam", (ya), con lo que las variaciones a lo largo de los territorios y el tiempo multiplican las diferencias. La "i", "I", también sirvió para escribir y pronunciar nombres con la forma, pero con sonido distinto, "Y", Iaiysus, Yaliso ó iaculum, jabalina, que igualmente se pronunciaban como "Y" = "LL". Otro tanto pasaba con la "u" Latina (también semivocal), podía existir como vocal, en el caso de "taurus" o pronunciarse como consonante, "ciuis".

Continuando con estas pronunciaciones, estas se intercalaban con otros sonidos. Algunas palabras y voces acabaron por transcribirse como "v" y pronunciarse como "u" o viceversa, "uita" en Latín, "vida" en Español. La diferencia entre la pronunciación de "v" y "u", por una serie de circunstancias, al final acabó por matizarse y la diferencias entre "v" y "b" desaparecieron en Español, no como en otras idiomas. Por tanto en latín no existen muchas palabras con la variante "hua".

En este sentido, tenemos adverbios como "huc", hacia aquí, acá, aquí, "hucine", otro adv. interrog. "hui", como interjección de sorpresa y algunos pronombres demostrativos como "hunc, haec, huius, huic...".

Otras pocas palabras en español como "huebos", del latín "opus", como cosa necesaria, "huebra" del latín "opera", la tierra que se labra en un día, la voz en español "huebrero", el que trabaja en la "huebra", también huerto de "hortus", "huesa" del latín, fassa, fosa, sepultura, "hueso" de ossum, hueca, como muesca, lugar donde la hebra se va hilando, de origen incierto. En español, del euskera "Huarte", Ur-arte, "entre aguas", También del griego "huero", estéril, huevo. Igualmente en diccionarios antiguos se pueden encontrar otras voces  "hua"/"hue" en desuso.

En general, el hecho de que en el propio Latín apenas existan vocablos "hua"/"hue" es una de las razones de que en Español tampoco hayamos tenido por esta vía un desarrollo de palabras con esa misma entrada "hua".

Del árabe tampoco nos ha quedado mucho, quizás "huri", mujer de gran belleza que habita en el paraíso, según el Corán. Mujer adolescente.

Por último, ya que el tema daría para más, y sin entrar en el ámbito de la "W" y la "U", "GU" o "GÜ", es cierto que gracias a mayas, incas y otros pueblos de América las voces "Hua" aumentaron en el léxico español, al menos para indicar nombres, lugares, poblaciones y otras palabras como huaquea, huaquero o huarache.

Espero que te haya servido o hayas entendido parte de la complejidad de este aspecto del español. Gracias. Diego.

P.D. En español, "Hua" o "Gua", es la forma en que imitamos o decimos que los niños pequeños están llorando. "Gua-Gua" Puede ser algo relacionado con un perro o un autobús.

Comment: Sobre la pronunciación de la B y la V en latín – había frecuentes faltas de ortografía, indicando que su pronunciación era idéntica. Para más info 
sobre la evolución de la V  > https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/325/when-did-the-consonant-u-i-e-v-begin-to-be-pronounced-as-the-fricative-v-i