# Translation-golf XVIII - Fake memories

Tags: traducción, translation-golf

> This game is already over.
>   The winner is [walen](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/13628) with [a proposal of just 184 characters](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/22310/12637).

Welcome to a new edition of the game!
If this is your first time, there's some info for beginners at the end of this post.

---

This time I'd like to propose a text taken from the *[Blade Runner](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0083658/)* movie. Yes, the original one, the one from 1982. The following excerpt is actually spoken in the movie by two different characters (Deckard and Rachael), and is related to the fake memories implanted in the artificial brains of the replicants. I have joined the sentences in one paragraph (consider that the following is said by Deckard to Rachael):

> Remember when you were six? You and your brother snuck into an empty building through a basement window. You were going to play doctor. He showed you his, but when it got to be your turn you chickened and ran; you remember that? You ever tell anybody that? Your mother, Tyrell, anybody? Remember the spider that lived outside your window? Orange body, green legs. Watched her build a web all summer, then one day there's a big egg in it. The egg hatched... and a hundred baby spiders came out... and they ate her.
>
> <sub>(397 caracteres)</sub>

You can watch the scene here: https://youtu.be/8BYSYE1zXUw?t=87 (I suppose this is a non-official video.)

I don't have access now to the official Spanish translation (for Spain) of the movie dialogue, so I'll come up with a non-golfed translation of my own:

> ¿Recuerdas cuando tenías seis años? Tu hermano y tú os habíais colado en un edificio vacío a través de una ventana del sótano. Ibais a jugar a los médicos. Él te la enseñó, pero cuando llegó tu turno te acobardaste y huiste, ¿lo recuerdas? ¿Se lo has contado a alguien? ¿A tu madre, a Tyrell, a alguien? ¿Recuerdas la araña que vivía por fuera de tu ventana? De cuerpo naranja y patas verdes. La observaste tejer una red todo el verano, y un día apareció en ella un huevo enorme. El huevo eclosionó... y cientos de arañitas salieron de él... y se la comieron.
>
>  <sub>(430 caracteres)</sub>

---

The goal is to translate the given text to Spanish, using as few letters as possible, while keeping all the original text's meaning and concepts more or less intact.

- Rules: [Translation-golf rules](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2592/5481)
- Letter counter: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2ermv0rh/2/embedded/result/)

You may want to check past [translation-golf](/questions/tagged/translation-golf) questions to get a feel of the game dynamics and the kind of answers expected.

Want to share translation ideas, ask for clarifications or just tease other contesters?
Join us in [La Tertulia](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46061/la-tertulia), Spanish.SE's official chat room!

Have fun!

Comment: Una duda ahora que he leído tu traducción, ¿cuando dice:  *Your mother, Tyrell, anybody?* le pregunta si se lo contó a Tyrell o le habla a Tyrell?

Comment: @blonfu he editado la pregunta para especificar qué personajes son. Tyrell es otro replicante, no es la madre de la que hablan ni el personaje al que se dirige.

Comment: Ok. Lo había entendido mal

Comment: @CarlosAlejo sería posible tener un link a la scène ? Pienso que ayudaría a comprender un poco mejor generalmente.

Comment: @user277143 he añadido un enlace a un vídeo que he encontrado en YouTube con la escena. De hecho viendo el vídeo parece que dice que la araña "lived _in a bush_ outside your window". Lo del arbusto no estaba en el texto que yo copié y no lo voy a introducir ahora que faltan menos de dos días para terminar el juego.

Comment: @CarlosAlejo Veyendo la vídeo comprendo que no eran retóricas las preguntas. Gracias.

Comment: Kiitos paljon. Intentaré encontrar algo interesante.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### <strike>250 243 240 212</strike> 184 caracteres

> A los 6, ¿[evocas](http://dle.rae.es/?w=evocar)? Con tu [tato](http://dle.rae.es/?w=tato) por el [vano](http://dle.rae.es/?id=bLIFqld#Lb35var) del sótano de la casa vacía, a jugar a médicos... [Huiste](http://dle.rae.es/srv/search?w=huir) al verlo. ¿Lo supo tu mami, Tyrell...? La araña de tu ventana, ¿sí? Naranja, pativerde. El estío tejiendo, ya viste. Y un día fue mamá: 100 bebés. [Jamáron](http://dle.rae.es/srv/search?w=jamar)la.

- Cambio los continuos *¿recuerdas?* por *¿sí?*, que sirven el mismo propósito de confirmar que la persona está siguiendo el hilo y efectivamente recuerda.
- Omito lo de colarse, queda implícito al indicar que entran por el vano (si no se estuviesen colando, entrarían por la puerta).
- El objetivo de jugar a médicos a los seis años, creo que todos lo sabemos. Al decir que huyó al verlo, se entiende que fue al ver "eso".
- La acción de huir suele implicar miedo, viene en la definición.
- Cambio toda la parte de *"You ever tell (...) Anybody?"* por *¿Lo supo tu mami, Tyrell...?*, que con los puntos suspensivos mantiene el significado de preguntarle si alguna vez se lo contó a ellos o a otros.
- De patas verdes: pativerde. Composición similar a [patiblanco](http://dle.rae.es/?id=S9K6tOa).
- Cuando una araña teje, suele ser su red, no es necesario especificarlo salvo que sea otra cosa distinta.
- Las arañas se convierten en mamás mediante la puesta de huevos y el nacimiento de sus arañitas a partir de los mismos.
- Uso cifras en vez de palabras para los números. No hay nada en las reglas ni a favor ni en contra. Para esta edición se ha permitido, pero [podéis votar en el debate](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2702/13628) sobre si incorporarlo a las reglas o no.

Comment: ¡Increíble! No quería leer tu traducción hasta tener la mía, me he quedado lejisimos de tu marca. Por cierto, Tyrell es un hombre.

Comment: llegue a pensar en usar "evocar" pero me parecía que no cuadraba mucho... pero parece que lo has ubicado bien

Answer (score 5):

## <del>248</del> <del>238</del> <del>234</del> <del>235</del> <del>218</del> <del>210</del> 190 caracteres

No prometo que sea ni español, tampoco bueno:

> ¿No pasaste por la ventana del sótano vacío con tu hermano jugando a "médicos" a los 6? Él la sacó; ¿tú? Huiste. ¿Callaste? ¿Con mamá, Tyrell? ¿Y la *Nigma walckenaeri* tras tu ventana que comieron las mil del huevo en su red que viste tejer el estío?

- La pregunta negativa necesita verificación de que la otra persona recuerda -> puede substituirse a recordar.
- Si es posible [defenestrar](http://dle.rae.es/srv/search?m=30&w=defenestrar), tiene que ser posible hacer el inverso, enfenestrar. (reemplazando el 'de' por 'en')
- La cuantidad de arañitas no fue exacta, puedo remplazar cientos con mil
- ¿Qué otra cosa puede nacer del huevo de una araña sino arañitas?

Edit 1:

- Un sótano tiene que partenecer a un edificio y lo importante del edificio vacío es que nadie hubiera molestado a los dos niños. Si digo que el sótano era vacío y cuento el tipo de cosas que han heco dentro de el, es claro que no había nadie cerca.
- Buscar el lugar para jugar es una parte del juego.

Edit 2:

- detrás de -> tras

Edit 3:

- hacerse comer -> comer
- niñas nacidas -> las mil nacidas (había olvidado la cuantidad)

Edit 4:

- el te la mostró el la sacó
- cambié la estructura: las preguntas del texto de origen son más o menos retóricas: pueden ser reemplazadas como así.
- Si me prohíben mi pobre 'enfenestrarse', <del>tengo que robar el 'pativerde' (y en la versión en Fines es mejor: es posible aglutinar palabras en Fines: ikkunantausviherjalkahämähäkki describe la araña pativerdonaranja tras la ventana)</del> o no.
- <del>Según la RAE, 'luna' puede querer decir 'cristal' en algunos casos. Si un hispanohablante verdadero podría decirme si es o no uno de esos casos, sería muy majo. http://dle.rae.es/?id=NhwJXco (la definición siete)</del>

Edit 5:

- Viendo la video comprendo que las preguntas no eran retóricas.

Edit 6:

- seis -> 6
- tú no -> ¿Tú? Admito que lo robé, pero también puede ser muy difícil sacar el 'lo' para una niña. Edit: Aquí quiero mantenerlo; mejora el texto realmente y lo hubiera hecho yo mismo.
  -> Quito la palabra 'nacidas': si vienes de un huevo, has nacido de él. También hace que 'las mil' devienen arañas.

Edit 7:

- Ambos saben de qué sótano hablan -> del sótano.

Edit 8:

- La *Nigma walckenaeri* es una araña naranja con patas verdes.  Es una de las relativemente poco comunas especies que tejen y además vive en arbustes como lo dice el texto de origen en la película. Es también muy común y vive en jardines.

Si hay algun Finohablante aquí, le invito a mejorar este:

> Ryömithän veljinesi kuuden vanhana tyhjän kellarin ikkunasta tohtorileikkiin? Hän näytti; pakenit vuorollasi. Kerroitko äidille? Tyrellille? Kellekään? Entä munasta kuoriutuneen poikasmassan syömä oranssi ikkunantausviherjalkahämähäkki, jonka kesäverkonrakennusta katselit?

<del>285</del> <del>250</del> 240 caracteres

Me da risa el hecho que en Finés tenga <del>59</del> <del>27</del> 26 palabras; no intento minimizar esa medida, pero es menos que ninguna versión en español.

Comment: Tienes algunos leves fallos, pero sí, se puede decir que es español. :-) Con algunas pequeñas correcciones será una propuesta muy competitiva. Y finés no sé, pero la pinta es alucinante.

Comment: ¿Podrías nombrarmelos? Y para lo que tiene que ver con el Finés: es un idioma muy aglutinativo: una araña con patas verdes puede ser viherjalkahämähäkki [vihreä

Comment: Son pequeños fallos ortográficos, si me permites te los corrijo. Asegúrate luego de volver a contar los caracteres, que con el móvil me resulta complicado.

Comment: Gracias para auydarme.

Comment: Hecho. He visto que te falta la parte de entrar "por la ventana del sótano". Si la omites debes explicar por qué, el resto de traducciones lo han incluido.

Comment: He simplemente olvidado... Si es posible decir 'defenestrar', ¿porqué no sería posible...?

Comment: La palabra "enfenestrar" no existe en español, pero entiendo cómo la has construido. De hecho me parece una palabra genial, el problema es que no aparece en el diccionario, y las reglas dicen que debe aparecer. Si no aparece, debes explicar cómo la has construido (qué prefijos y sufijos has usado y enlaces al diccionario que lo demuestren).

Comment: Y ahora, ¿es mejor?

Comment: El razonamiento me parece genial y la palabra muy ocurrente, pero lo voy a consultar con la RAE a ver qué opinan. Cuando tenga tiempo. Lo puedes dejar así de momento.

Comment: Veyendo que la raiz es el Latin (¿Dedónde sacastéis la palabra 'ventana'?), tengo que admitir que no es seguro.

Comment: https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/17669/12637

Comment: Tras consultarlo a la RAE, siento informarte de que [no me validan el uso de "enfenestrar"](https://twitter.com/RAEinforma/status/909700490908270592). Deberás buscar una alternativa.

Comment: No me gusta, pero no es una sorpresa.

Comment: Tu propuesta matando el texto es demasiado matadora, elimina demasiados matices. Puedes dejarla si quieres, pero no será aceptada como respuesta válida. Sí he validado, en todo caso, el uso de números para esta edición del TG, por lo que puedes usarlos también si quieres.

Comment: Bien, te comprendo. Y en la otra, hace falta algo?

Comment: @walen y gracias

Comment: "Luna" se usa para los cristales de los coches y para cristales muy grandes, como un escaparate de una tienda. No se usa en las ventanas normales de una casa

Comment: Bien, voy a arreglarlo. (Y gracias)

Comment: Que opinas (@CarlosAlejo) del "callarse"?

Comment: No se dice "te huiste" sino "huiste", además son dos letras menos :)

Comment: Gracias, en francés es reflexivo (s'enfuir). (Pienso que fue eso que me hizo equivocarme) Si hay otras faltas, dígame. Por ejemplo, ¿es callarse con alguien?

Comment: Puedo quitarlas. Las reglas podrían ser más claras con eso

Comment: ¿Ladrón? Quizás, pero intento ser un ladrón legal y gracioso. ( ;

Comment: El uso de "te callaste" me parece acertado. Estás haciendo la pregunta inversa: si se calló en vez de si lo contó. Ahora mismo la traducción como está me parece correcta.

Comment: mira lo que dijo blonfu acerca de "te huiste" y revisa tu texto para reducir caracteres... (@walen me va a odiar o quizá lo aproveche si lo lee...) Y en cuanto al 'veyendo' de los comentarios, es 'viendo'

Comment: @VeAqui No comprendo lo de ”te huiste”, lo he ya corrigido (o al menos creo que). Gracias por el veyendo / viendo.

Comment: La última frase tiene un par de cosas raras, yo la pondría así (son los mismos caracteres): _Y la Nigma walckenaeri tras tu ventana que comieron las mil del huevo en su red que viste tejer en el estío_

Comment: @walen Pues pensaba que "te huiste" estaba mal, suena horriblemente extraño.

Comment: Aunque @walen ha sido el vencedor, renuncia al derecho a preguntar así que como segundo clasificado tienes 48 horas para proponer un nuevo reto. Pasado ese tiempo se abrirá la veda para que cualquiera pueda plantear un nuevo translation-golf. También puedes ceder el derecho a preguntar, que en su caso irá al tercer clasificado.

Answer (score 5):

**<strike>299</strike> <strike>292</strike> <strike>288</strike> <strike>275</strike> 246 caracteres**

> ¿Recordás, a tus seis años? Ibas con tu hermano a una obra vacía por la ventana del sótano, a jugar al médico. Se peló y huiste apenada; ¿recordás? ¿nadie sabe? ¿tu amá, Tyrell, nadie? ¿O la araña ocre, pativerde de afuera de tu ventana? hizo una red en el estío, un día puso un huevote, nacieron muchas arañitas y fue comida.

Vamos letra a letra, verbo a verbo...

- Siendo pasado, creo que puede usarse el imperfecto (ibas)
- Uso el O como remplazo del último *Remember* (como un O inclusivo de la lógica
- La araña termina siendo comida por las recien nacidas

Comment: Sería un error muy gordo no validar el Diccionario de americanismos. Me ha encantado el uso de "pelar", por cierto.

Comment: @walen, si bien cometí errores sin intención (el voseo y el amá hacen parte de mi habla cotidiana en Colombia, y el pelar si lo tomé prestado de centroamérica), al confirmar se puede dar una unión en estos 2 países... en ese caso, a no defraudar a Asturias ni a Monterroso...

Answer (score 4):

#### 334 caracteres

> ¿Recuerdas tus seis años? Con tu hermano os colasteis en un edificio vacío por una ventana del sótano, para jugar a médicos. Te la enseñó, pero tú no: te acobardaste y huiste, ¿recuerdas? ¿Lo explicaste? ¿A tu madre, a Tyrell, a alguien? ¿Recuerdas la araña viviendo fuera de tu ventana, cuerpo naranja, patas verdes? En verano la viste tejer una red. Allí un huevo grande apareció, nació... y sus cientos de arañitas se la comieron.

Preveo un uso intenso de adjetivos extraídos de [Translation-golf VI: Sandkings by George R. R. Martin](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/20863/1674)

Answer (score 3):

### <strike>326 305 273</strike> 251 caracteres

> ¿Recuerdas a los seis?: una casa vacía, un sotano con ventana, entrar con tu hermano, jugar a médicos. Él la sacó, tu turno: miedo y huir; ¿Le dijiste a mamá, Tyrell, alguien? ¿Y la araña naranja de patas verdes fuera de tu ventana? La viste tejer su red todo el verano, un día un gran huevo se abrió con cien arañas... y se la jalaron.

Este texto parece complicado de reducir, pongo lo que tengo y veré si mas adelante puedo mejorarlo.

Comment: Hay mucho que se puede reducir aquí, tienes mucho margen aún. Lo único es que la primera frase parece que dice si se acuerda de seis personas. Puedes mejorarla con "¿Te acuerdas, a los seis?"

Comment: Tienes razón, estuve cambiando esa frase y al final  he quitado *años* olvidándome de cambiar la preposición.